# Metasploitable 3 - System error 67

Tags: windows-server-2008, metasploit

I am trying to set up Metasploitable 3 (VirtualBox) on my Ubuntu 16.04.
I have done everything according to the guidelines of the inventors (https://github.com/rapid7/metasploitable3) when it comes to dependencies etc.

However, when I'm trying to start it (via `vagrant up --provision win2k8`) I get this nasty little error, that I just can't fix.

It always says:

`win2k8: System error 67 has occurred.`

`win2k8: The network name cannot be found.`

`The following WinRM command responded with a non-zero exit status.`

`Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!`

`cmd /q /c "c:\tmp\vagrant-shell.bat"`

`Stdout from the command:`

`CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.`

`Stderr from the command:`

`System error 67 has occurred.`

`The network name cannot be found.`

I just can't find anything out on the internet. I only "know" it has something to do with network settings. But I don't know what to do now.

I'd appreciate some help!